# How to get current local date and time in Adonisjs (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am working on an AdonisJs app which is on V4.1 and i am trying to get the local time and date for my app. Normally in laravel you can do something like this `{{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}}` which gives `Wednesday, 01 July 2020 at 07:00 PM`

How can i do that in my adonis js project?

Answer (score 1):

Adonis uses by default [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). To get something like your example:

```
moment().format('MM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // July 3rd 2020, 10:49:29 am
```

Is not necessary import

Answer (score 1):

To today, Adonis uses Luxon (by moment), try it:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'

const newDate = DateTime.local().toISO()
//'2023-07-19T19:41:10.000+00:00'
```

For more formats or whatever, check the documentation https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting